# Удалить подстроку из строки

Tags: javascript, imacros

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace('https://','');")
```

Как поправить код, чтобы удалялось `https://` и `http://`, а не только `https://` ?

Comment: `.replace(/https?:\/\//,'')`

Comment: да, как раз без "/g " заработало. У меня ещё один вопрос по imacros. Вот я допустим спарсила какой-то текст. Ну например... "Мама мыла раму". Как мне прописать в коде так, чтобы слова "Мама" и "раму" удалить, а оставить только слово "мыла". Это тоже можно осуществить через ".replace" ? Извините, что возможно некорректно выражаюсь)) Надеюсь вы меня поняли)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведённом вами примере, в метод `replace` вы передали обычную строку, которую метод будет искать и заменять на строку, которую вы передали вторым параметром. Однако, в вашем случае было бы уместно использование регулярных выражений и передавать первым параметром не обычную строку, а объект RegExp. В таким случае, метод будет искать вхождения в согласии с вашим регулярным выражением. Например:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/https?:\/\//,'');")
```

Примитивный пример на быструю руку:

```js
function update_elem(){
  elem_1 = $('#elem_1').text().replace(/https*:\/\//,'');
  elem_2 = $('#elem_2').text().replace(/https*:\/\//,'');
  
  $('#elem_1').text(elem_1);
  $('#elem_2').text(elem_2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem_1">http://jsfiddle.net/</div>
<div id="elem_2">https://jsfiddle.net/</div>
<button onclick="update_elem();">Обновить</button>
```

Comment: У меня ещё один вопрос по imacros. Вот я допустим спарсила какой-то текст. Ну например... "Мама мыла раму". Как мне прописать в коде так, чтобы слова "Мама" и "раму" удалить, а оставить только слово "мыла". Это тоже можно осуществить через ".replace" ? Извините, что возможно некорректно выражаюсь)) Надеюсь вы меня поняли) P.S.: Не удаляйте коммент, я сама потом удалю, как мне ответят. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Машуня ни в коем случае не удаляйте комментарии: ни свои, ни чужие!  Это нарушает целостность обсуждения и может помешать другим участникам.

Comment: @Машуня да, это тоже можно сделать с помощью метода `реплейс`. Но как вам сообщил @And - это уже совсем другая история. :)

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас задам новый вопрос, по правилам)

Comment: @Машуня также не забывайте принимать ответ, который помог вам и является наилучшим ответом на ваш вопрос. Сделать это можно нажав на галочку. Советую вам ознакомиться с этими ссылками: [Краткий туториал по системе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) и [Справка > Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)